# Problem with VBA code that adds a formula with cell reference to other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

When a userform button is clicked the following code runs, there is an error with the last three lines of the code, something to do with the `Locations` variable.

The code must create a new worksheet with name entered by user and also add a row of data to the "Locations" worksheet with the name of new location, total sum of expenses in the newly created worksheet and sum of expense for each person in the newly created worksheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set Locations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locations")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Location As String

Location = TextBox1().Value

If Len(Trim(Location)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a location"
Else
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = Location
    Range("A1").Value = "Type"
    Range("B1").Value = "Paid By"
    Range("C1").Value = "Amount"
    End With

    LastRow = Worksheets("Locations").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Worksheets("Locations").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Location
    Worksheets("Locations").Range("B" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUM(" & Location & "!C:C)"
    Worksheets("Locations").Range("C" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & Location & "!B:B;Locations!C2;" & Location & "!C:C)"
    Worksheets("Locations").Range("D" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & Location & "!$B:$B;Locations!D2;" & Location & "!$C:$C)"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What values do you have in TextBox1

Comment: Since you say the problem is with `Locations` how is it defined? What is it's `Dim`? I find it strange that the variable is instantiated (`Set`) but not used in the code. OTOH `Worksheets("Locations")` is used many times?

Comment: Why not just use ws.Name in stead of location? Also, I agree with Cindy.

Comment: TextBox1 is string entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If there's any chance your sheet names havve spaces then you need to quote them in your formulas
- When creating formulas in VBA the list separator is always a comma (unless you use FormulaLocal when you can use your local list separator, but for various reasons that's not a good idea)

Untested:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Location As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Locations As Worksheet

    Set Locations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locations")
    Location = Trim(TextBox1.Value)

    If Len(Location) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a location"
    Else

        With ThisWorkbook
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With
        ws.Name = Location
        ws.Range("A1").Value = "Type"
        ws.Range("B1").Value = "Paid By"
        ws.Range("C1").Value = "Amount"


        With Locations.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            .Cells(1).Value = Location
            .Cells(2).Formula = "=SUM('" & Location & "'!C:C)"
            .Cells(3).Formula = "=SUMIF('" & Location & "'!B:B,Locations!C2,'" & Location & "'!C:C)"
            .Cells(4).Formula = "=SUMIF('" & Location & "'!$B:$B,Locations!D2,'" & Location & "'!$C:$C)"
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There are spaces in the sheets names. This code seems to work, thanks